# Are בישול on Shabbos and בישול of Meat and milk the same?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, yoreh-deah, lomdus

Are the qualifications for being called בישול (cooking) the same for Shabbos (e.g., frying is a question in Halacha if it is recognized as Cooking to say אין בישול אחר בישול - there is no such thing as cooking after choking) as they are for being responsible for Cooking meat and milk together, or are they different? Please illustrate with an example.

Comment: Not directly related, but the laws of bishul on shabbos and on yom tov (for eruv tavshilin) are different--this in the name of Rav Yaakov (iirc) Yosef.  Example: you have a pot of soup in your fridge.  On shabbos, you aren't allowed to bring it to a boil.  But you can on yom tov for shabbos, even if you didn't make an eruv tavshilin.

Comment: @JXG, do you mean [him](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%28%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A3%29)? Also, why doesn't the general rule against _hachana_ apply to that pot, even if there's no _bishul_ issue?

Comment: @msh210, haha, no, I mean the son of Rav Ovadia.  The general rule for hachana is that on Yom Tov, you are allowed to prepare for Shabbat, particularly for things that are not allowed on Shabbat but are allowed on Yom Tov.  A detailed answer is beyond the scope of my brain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [the Aruch HaShulchan YD 87:10](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%96) where he says that you cannot bring a proof from the laws of Shabbos to say that frying is a problem of cooking meat and milk.  Similarly, by smoking (in #25) he writes the same. In #31 he discusses bishul acher bishul, but seems to conclude that again, despite the rules of Shabbos, the rules of basar b'chalav are different.

Comment: +1, excellent find, but note that in :25 (if the linked-to version is accurate) he quotes the _P'ri Chadash_ as saying that what's true for _Shabas_ is true for _basar b'chalav_ — so apparently the _AHS_'s is not the only opinion on this issue.

Comment: Wow !!!thanx alot amazing research team we have here I think staying here long  enough and taking part of the conversations  makes you an aromatic Talmid Chacham

Answer (score 2):

To some extent it seems to be. See [Hullin 108b](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4822&size=1), Rashi DH "Aherim" and Ritva on that Rashi. He says that he level of Bishul that qualifies as a lav for Basar BeHalav is Ben D'rosai

Answer (score 1):

They definitely are the same.

There are hundreds of proofs for this.

Just one that springs immediately to mind:
עיין [סימן ק״ה ש״ך ס״ק ה׳](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&pgnum=496) ו[שפתי דעת על אתר](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&pgnum=567).

Comment: You mean _Sifse Daas_?

Comment: Yes. I meant sifsei daas. Typed on my iPhone and it changed it. Thanks.